# I have an error in plyer.facades.Notification.notify() that is TypeError: Notification.notify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

```py
# import Notification Method from plyer module
from plyer.facades import Notification 
# notify function declaration
def notifyMe(title,text):
    Notification.notify(
        title=title,
        message=text,
        app_icon=None,
        timeout=5
    )
        
# main function declaration
if __name__ == '__main__':
    notifyMe("Notification","Just Click here to see what it is")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an instance method as a class method.
You should create an object from the Notification class first, and then use it to call this method. Or use a Singleton "notification" provided for you by the package developer.

Maybe this documentation will be helpful: https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/facades/notification.py

```
# To send notification::
from plyer import notification
title = 'plyer'
message = 'This is an example.'
notification.notify(title=title, message=message)
```